# Any way to dynamically change the value of repeat for gridTemplateColumns using variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

```
let selectNum = 16; 
container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(selectNum, 1fr)";
```

I am trying to use the value of selectNum dynamically.
Is there any way to use selectNum variable in gridTemplateColumns repeat function?

Comment: you mean concatenate the string? `"repeat(" + selectNum + ", 1fr)"`

Answer (score 0):

just use javascript templating like this :

```
let selectNum = 16; 
container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${selectNum}, 1fr)`;
```